# How to start a program with lower priority in WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp

is there a way to set the program priority in Windows XP directly by shortcut?

As for now, I start the program and use the Task-Manager to set the priority to low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a batch file to start your application with the desired priority level:

```
cmd /c start /<priority> <application>
```

for example

```
cmd /c start /low application.exe
```

Comment: Thanks. I could have looked here yesterday, it would have saved me a little time. :-)

Comment: The application.exe does start as expected, but when I look in the Task-Manager the priority is still shown as normal. Why is that?

Comment: With the "upgrade" to SP3 of WinXP it now shows the expected priority.